# Using LuaLaTeX to calculate lengths in cm to be used in TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, lua

What I am trying to accomplish is the calculation of a length in cm, which I need for a TikZ drawing. The calculation itself is not trivial (cubic root, which I turned into `math.log` and `math.exp`), thus I have decided to use Lua, which will also allow me to define the number of decimal points through `string.format`. Out of this calculation, I would like to return a LaTeX length definition in cm.
Now I have finally arrived at a half-baked solution, that seems to set the length but for some reason the length dbe is still as zero. As per MWE, I am printing the command to the Log as well, see `print(tmp)` for debugging and if I Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V this output directly, the length definition works. Where am I going wrong with printing/returning the commands back to LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes,calc}

% Define a variable as a length
\newcommand{\nvar}[2]{%
    \newlength{#1}
    \setlength{#1}{#2}
}

% Define a few constants for transmission line drawing
\nvar{\rx}{0.33333cm}
\nvar{\diameter}{0.6cm}
\nvar{\db}{2cm}

% calculate some other dimensions (cubic root using ln and e)
\begin{luacode}
rx=0.33333
db=2
dbe= math.exp(math.log(rx*db*db)/3)
tmp = "\\newlength{\\dbe}\\setlength{\\dbe}{" .. string.format("%.2f", dbe) .. "cm}"
print(tmp)
tex.print(tmp)
\end{luacode}


\begin{document}

The \LaTeX lengths:\\
\the\rx\\
\the\diameter\\
\the\db \\
\the\dbe


\begin{tikzpicture}
        \colorlet{left}{black}
        \tikzset{line core/.style={draw=red,ultra thick, circle,fill=orange,minimum height=\dbe,anchor=center},%
       line conductor/.style={shading = axis,circle, left color=left, right color=left!30!white,shading angle=180, anchor=center, minimum height=\dbe}
        }

        % looping through available phases
        \foreach \phase/\centreX/\centreY in{1/0/0,2/4/0,3/2/3}
        {
            \coordinate (centre\phase) at (\centreX,\centreY);
            \node [line core] at (centre\phase) {}; 
            % drawing a phase transmission line - need to add at least three or four conductors
            \foreach \angle in {90,30,150}
            {
                \node [line conductor] at ($ (centre\phase) + (\angle:\diameter)$) {};
                \node [line conductor] at ($ (centre\phase) + (-\angle:\diameter)$) {};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The output I get through `print(tmp)` in the log is:

```
\newlength{\dbe}\setlength{\dbe}{1.10cm}
```

edit: using MacTeX/TeXLive 2015 with all the latest packages through tlmgr

Comment: It's just a constant number it seems you are not doing a calculation based on input from the document, so why use lua at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, that is true. The question here was the first one, a follow up question would have been how I could take input from a given length, say \rx and do the calculation for \dbe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing a string such as

```
\newlength{\dbe}\setlength\dbe{...}
```

is not the same as executing the instructions contained in the string.

Since you've already set up the utility macro `\nvar` to define a length variable and assign a value to the newly-defined variable, I would take the following tack: Inside the Lua-side group, set up a function called, say, `mycalc` that performs the cube-root calculations and returns a length string. Then, make use of `\nvar` to define `\dbe` as follows:

```
\nvar{\dbe}{\directlua{mycalc(0.33333,2,"cm")}}
```

Note that in the code below, I don't employ the `string.format` function that's in your code -- I don't see the need to limit the precision of the calculation at this point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes,calc}

% Define a variable as a length
\newcommand{\nvar}[2]{\newlength{#1}\setlength{#1}{#2}}

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function mycalc ( rx , db , unit )
  return (  tex.sprint ( math.exp(math.log(rx*db*db)/3) .. unit ) )
end
\end{luacode}

% Define a few constants
\nvar{\rx}{0.33333cm}
\nvar{\diameter}{0.6cm}
\nvar{\db}{2cm}
\nvar{\dbe}{\directlua{mycalc(0.33333,2,"cm")}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
The \LaTeX\ lengths:\\
\the\rx\\
\the\diameter\\
\the\db \\
\the\dbe


\begin{tikzpicture}
        \colorlet{left}{black}
        \tikzset{line core/.style={draw=red,ultra thick, circle,fill=orange,minimum height=\dbe,anchor=center},%
       line conductor/.style={shading = axis,circle, left color=left, right color=left!30!white,shading angle=180, anchor=center, minimum height=\dbe}
        }

        % looping through available phases
        \foreach \phase/\centreX/\centreY in{1/0/0,2/4/0,3/2/3}
        {
            \coordinate (centre\phase) at (\centreX,\centreY);
            \node [line core] at (centre\phase) {}; 
            % drawing a phase transmission line - need to add at least three or four conductors
            \foreach \angle in {90,30,150}
            {
                \node [line conductor] at ($ (centre\phase) + (\angle:\diameter)$) {};
                \node [line conductor] at ($ (centre\phase) + (-\angle:\diameter)$) {};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In the preceding code, the "variables" `\rx` and `\db` are hardcoded and their values thus have to be entered again as constants in the `\nvar` call that sets up `\dbe`. To streamline the process, one can replace the instructions

```
\nvar{\rx}{0.33333cm}
\nvar{\diameter}{0.6cm}
\nvar{\db}{2cm}
\nvar{\dbe}{\directlua{mycalc(0.33333,2,"cm")}}
```

with

```
\newcommand\rxval{0.33333}
\newcommand\dbval{2}   

\nvar{\rx}{\rxval cm}
\nvar{\diameter}{0.6 cm}
\nvar{\db}{\dbval cm}
\nvar{\dbe}{\directlua{mycalc(\rxval,\dbval,"cm")}}
```

That way, one only needs to modify `\rxval` and `\dbval` in order to modify `\rx`, `\db`, *and* `\dbe`.

Comment: I had not thought about creating a function, but that works brilliantly. I am also now making use of defining a number first `\def\rxVal{0.33333}`, which I then use to derive a length from `\nvar{\rx}{\rxVal cm}` and then finally in `\nvar{\dbe}{\directlua{mycalc(\rxVal, \dbVal)}}`. The idea was to parameterise these values, so that I can reuse  it whilst creating my TikZ drawing.

Comment: @aXon - I'm glad my answer works for you. :-) I've posted an addendum that formalizes your idea of defining macros containing (scalar) numers first and then using these macros to automate the definition of the length variables `\rx`, `\db`, and `\dbe`.